# Dropdown-menu of datepicker displays wrong inside angularjs modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, modal-dialog

I am using a jquery datepicker [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) inside a modal on AngularJS. The problem is that the position of the dropdown-menu is wrong on the screen. I think is something related to the modal, because outside the modal it is OK.
I am using *bootstrap 3.1.1*.
I already tried to set z-index: 1151 but this doesn't work. Could someone help me?

HTML:

```
  <div class="modal fade" tabindex='-1'>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close('N')" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{ModalController.label + titulo}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form name="myFormNewColab" method="post">
                <div class="form-group" ng-show="tipo=='Colaborador'&&op==1">
                    <label>Nome do colaborador: *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="newColab" class="form-control" ng-value="nome" ng-model="newColab" required/>
                </div>
            </form>
            <form name="myFormColab" method="post">
                <div class="form-group" ng-show="tipo=='Lavoura'&&op==1">
                    <label>Nome do colaborador: *</label>
                    <select name="novoColaborador" ng-model="novoColaborador" ng-change="changedColab(novoColaborador)" ng-options="x.coNome for x in colabs" class="form-control" required></select>
                    <label>Data Colheita: *</label>
                    <div id="datapicker-container">
                        <input name="novaDataCol" class="form-control dp2" ng-model="novaDataCol" value="dataCol" required/>
                    </div>
                    <label>Selecione a roça: *</label>
                    <select ng-model="roOption" name="roOption" class="form-control" ng-change="changedRoca(roOption)" ng-options="x.roNome for x in rocas" required></select>
                    <label>Selecione a planta: *</label>
                    <select ng-disabled="myFormColab.roOption.$invalid||plantsRoc.length<=0" ng-model="plOption" name="plOption" class="form-control" ng-change="changedPlanta(plOption)" ng-options="x.plNome for x in plantsRoc" required></select>
                    <label>Variedade da planta: *</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="vrOption" ng-value="pl_variedade" name="vrOption" class="form-control" disabled/>
                    <label>Quantidade de caixas: *</label>
                    <input type="number" name="novoQtdPlantas" class="form-control" min="1" ng-model="novoQtdPlantas" required/>
                </div>
            </form>
```

JS:

```
            $scope.$watch('dataCol', function() {
                $('.dp2').datepicker({
                    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                    clearBtn: true,
                    todayBtn: true,
                    todayHighlight: true,
                    autoclose: true
                }).bind('changeDate', function onDateChange(ev) {
                    $scope.novaDataCol = ev.date;
                });
            });
```

**EDIT:**
[link to image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQh2k.png)

**EDIT2:** Problem solved! I was using an old version of bootstrap that couldn't support this feature. I have already updated to version 1.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `import {DatePipe} from "@angular/common";` directives to convert your format like

```
const datePipe= new DatePipe('en-US');
this.item.birthDate  = datePipe.transform(data['birthDate'], 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't very clear. The problem is not the format of the date, but the position of the dropdown-menu on the screen.

Comment: Could you send the modal css please.

Comment: I don't use a css to modal. I am only importing a js script to use it on my code (https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service). I edit my post and put a image of the problem.